# How do I access action and history from BrowserRouter in Matched route (v4)?

Tags: react-router

I'm using React Router v4 and using BrowserRouter.

[image]

This screenshot here shows that BrowserRouter's props have an `action="POP"`.

[image]

However, when my route is matched as in the screenshot above, RegisterMatch or MatchProvider are not receiving the action, history, etc. via props.

I see via https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4/website/components/FakeBrowser/index.js#L96 that there might need to be an injection of these props, but I'm not able to make sense of it or make it work.

Comment: It appears what I want is a ControlledRouter which is yet to be released (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3879)  In the meantime, I will try this: https://gist.github.com/steida/16da36887e6e6b466e12ba3a4ae6ce87

Answer (score 0):

Using `<Router />` with a history prop or `<BrowserRouter />` with a basename prop solves this.
e.g. `<Router history={history}>`

`<BrowserRouter>` ignores the history prop. To use a custom history, ' +
      'use `import { Router }` instead of `import { BrowserRouter as Router }`.